# Como receber e lidar com Notificações "IPN" do PagSeguro PHP

Tags: php

Queria saber como faço para lidar com as notificações do PagSeguro e salvar elas em LOG.txt

fiz oque esta nesta print http://prntscr.com/k08zyo
mais não funcionou..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jheyson boa noite.
Eu trabalhei muito com o pagseguro, e sempre quando precisava pegar a resposta e guardar em um log eu usava o [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-put-contents.php)

Comment: Não preciso necessariamente salvar em log quero pegar a resposta e tirar algumas informações dela por isso optei por salvar ela como log

Comment: Ah sim, entendi, você pode fazer o seguinte, entra no sandbox, pega o notificationCode e coloca direto no seu código, e claro não use o POST, assim você vai conseguir ver exatamente como vem o retorno, caso não consiga me avise que dou um exemplo para você.

Comment: O problema real é que o post não esta nem chegando ao mesmo site fiz o teste e não chega, na minha conta do PagSeguro esta tudo configurado o link de notificação

Comment: Esse é o problema, você está esperando chegar alguma coisa no seu site, e no caso o ideal seria você simular o que está chegando, que é o que estou propondo.

Ao invés de colocar $_POST['notificationCode'], coloque o notificationCode que pegou no sandbox, e pronto, vai ter todos os dados que vão chegar em seu site.

Mas o porque que não está chegando o POST, ai já não sei, teria que ver como você está fazendo o checkout.

Comment: O problema é que o próprio pagseguro não envia, fiz o teste colocando para quando o URL de notificação tiver qualquer acesso ele me envia um e-mail, fiz uma compra com outra conta e não chegou nada, acredito que pode ter algo errado não sei dizer oque é e nem o porque do post não chegar